# Azure AD Password Protection - Usable for Non-Microsoft Directories?

Tags: azure-active-directory, password-protection

Is it possible to use Azure AD Password Protection with other directories apart from Microsoft AD?

Comment: Did you mean that whether microsoft has provided some api or sdk to check if the password user set is a weak password?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, the Azure AD password protection function currently only exists in the AD tenant, and it cannot currently be used with other directories other than the AD tenant. Moreover, Microsoft also does not provide api or sdk for other directories to use.